# Socket Address in Computer Networks

Tags: sockets, http, networking, client-server

I read that in the server site – The local (server) socket address is provided by the OS and the remote (client) socket address is the address of the client that makes the connection. The server can find this socket address when a client tries to connect
to the server but in the Client Site – The local (client) socket address is provided by the OS.
What about the remote (server) socket address?

Comment: Servers use well-known port numbers, e.g. 80 for http.

Answer (score 0):

The client does need some way to find the IP address of the server it wants to connect to; the most common way to find the IP address is by starting with a hostname string (e.g. "stackoverflow.com" or whatever) that was either supplied by the user or hard-coded into the program, and using [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) to look up an IP address that corresponds to that hostname string.  The usual API for doing a DNS lookup is [getaddrinfo()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html), although older (or lazier) software might call the older [gethostbyname()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html) function instead.

Once the client has the IP address of the server it wants to connect to, it also needs to supply a port number; often the port number just a [well-known standard port number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) for a particular type of service (such as 80 for HTTP, or 22 for SSH).  If not, then the client will either have to "just know" what port number to use to contact the server, or it will need some other [mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking#Service_discovery) to figure out which port number to use.